# Inspect element hover behaviour different to page load

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm using an HTML table to try and achieve this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saggs.png

Here's my code:

```css
.i-am-a-content {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.buttons {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.buttons p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

tr>td+td {
  border-left-width: 60px;
}

tr+tr>td {
  border-top-width: 20px;
}

td p {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.i-am-text {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80)/* For IE8 and earlier */
  vertical-align: center;
}

div.i-am-text p {
  color: #2e2e2e;
  vertical-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=i-am-a-content>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="buttons">
        <h3>Button 1
          <h3>
      </td>
      <td class="i-am-text" rowspan="3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mea id quodsi efficiendi, sed eirmod salutatus at. Partem eruditi detraxit et mei. At mea modo laboramus sententiae. Alia autem ei est, meliore recusabo ocurreret cu sea. Sit in euismod volumus appareat, epicurei adipisci
          electram mei at. No affert patrioque maiestatis vim.Nec assum senserit in, eu pri detracto mandamus. Etiam consequat definitiones ut eum, admodum iracundia vix te. Cu est vivendo definitionem, meliore invenire eam no, harum definitionem conclusionemque
          vix te. Te possim torquatos vulputate vim, deleniti hendrerit an ius. Cu nam vero iudico conclusionemque. Dolorem gloriatur usu ne, agam consul reprimique te vix, quando aliquid scaevola nam no.Id rebum nemore alterum est. Mollis pertinacia
          vel at, posse movet officiis nec te. Nec cu ullum principes, pro ei homero option graecis. Libris graeci et sed, sea ei hendrerit efficiantur, sit ex accusam fabellas. Duo ut aliquam patrioque democritum.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="buttons">
        <h3>Button 2</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="buttons">
        <h3>Button 3</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Everything is working as it should be.

However, in my browser (Chrome) and I've also tested in Edge, the hover doesn't work. If I inspect the element in Chrome and select "hover" I can see the hover working as it should be (background change to red). But it doesn't work when I just load the web page.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why the behaviour works within inspect element but not in reality?

Comment: it's working fine here

Comment: It works fine here, and I'm using Chrome

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: I've pushed it live here to show it *not* working: http://dev.amydaynes.com/

Comment: What is not working? The hover color red works fine for me

Comment: @JelmerBouman Thanks for your reply. Can you confirm the hover on the "I am a copywriter" buttons is working for you here: http://dev.amydaynes.com/ ? It's so strange as they are definitely not working for me. By not working I mean nothing happens at all when I hover. I have tried clearing my browser's cache but to no avail.

Comment: .i-am-a-bg Has a z-index of -1, when I delete this z-index the hover works fine. Only problem is the div above this class is not showing when you remove the z-index. I think you have to build this in an other way. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: @insynco can you provide me online css file than i will check

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `position: relative;`

```
.i-am-a-bg {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

than hover is working

remove `position:relative;`

that why hover not working & the cursor geetting body first.

i think it's helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Removing z-index brings back the hover effect. But, you have used it for the visibility of the blocks as you have used positions for spacing.

No need to use positions and top for spacing alone. If there is any other use for position: relative you can keep it, otherwise please remove it and use margins for this spacing.

Margins are added instead of top, so, z-index and top is commented below, please remove them from your code.

```
.i-am-a-bg {
     background-color: #c7c7c7;
     position: relative;
     /* top: -180px; */
     /* z-index: -1; */
     /* padding-top: 250px; */
     padding-bottom: 180px;
     margin-bottom: 180px;
     margin-top: 70px; }
```

Comment: Hugely helpful. Thank you very much. z-Index was the main culprit!